# show that $R_{a,b}$ is a convex set

Tags: calculus

Question: set in the plane is called a convex set if the following holds: Whenever $u$ and $v$ belong to the set, so does $λu + (1 − λ)v$ for any scalar $λ \in (0,1)$. Consider the set $R_{a,b}$ with one corner at the origin and the “far” corner at the point $\langle a,b\rangle$. Explicitly
$$ R_{a,b} = \{ \langle x,y\rangle \mid   0 ≤ x ≤ a,0 ≤ y ≤ b\}. $$

Use the above deﬁnition to show that $R_{a,b}$ is a convex set.

how do $u$ and $v$ come into play if the set has $x$ and $y$ only?

Answer (score 1):

To show that $R_{a, b}$ is a convex set, you would start by choosing two points $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2) \in R_{a, b}$.  These two points would act as your $u$ and $v$ in the definition.  Now you have to check whether
$$ t(x_2, y_2) + (1-t)(x_1, y_1) \in R_{a, b} $$
for any $0 \leq t \leq 1$.  This amounts to checking
$$ (tx_2 + (1-t)x_1, ty_2 + (1-t)y_1) \in R_{a, b} $$
for any $0 \leq t \leq 1$.  So you must show
$$ 0 \leq tx_2 + (1-t)x_1 \leq a $$
*and*
$$ 0 \leq ty_2 + (1-t)y_1 \leq b $$
for any $0 \leq t \leq 1$.  Can you take it from here?

**EDIT**:
To show
$$ 0 \leq tx_2 + (1-t)x_1 \leq a, $$
start by noting $0 \leq x_1, x_2 \leq a$, which implies $0 \leq tx_2 \leq ta$ and $0 \leq (1-t)x_1 \leq (1-t)a$ for any $0 \leq t \leq 1$.  This implies
$$ 0 \leq tx_2 + (1-t)x_1 \leq ta + (1-t)a = a, $$
which is what we wanted.

Comment: does it just require algebraic manipulation?

Comment: I've edited the answer to include the calculation for the first inequality. The second is almost identical.